# Identificar uma pessoa através de regras (IA)

Tags: java, python

Necessito de um sistema que identifique uma pessoa (exatamente uma pessoa) através de regras (no caso, hábitos da tal pessoa) mas meu conhecimento em IA é muito raso. Existe alguma técnica apropriada para isso? De preferência, que seja aplicável em linguagens como Java e Python.

Comment: Oi Daniel, seja bem-vindo ao site. Seria legal uma lidinha no [Tour], em [Ask] e [Help] para se situar com o funcionamento do site. Apesar de ser uma dúvida que tem relação com programação, ela é um pouco ampla demais, eu diria até muito vaga. Seria importante você contextualizar melhor a situação, ou tentar fazer algo e trazer para cá as dúvidas um pouco mais elaboradas. Com um pouco mais de pontos, você pode participar do chat, que seria mais adequado para esse tipo de discussão preliminar até chegar numa dúvida na partde da programação propriamente dita.

Comment: Olá Daniel,lhe aconselho a dar um suporte pro seguinte link : http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence 

Esta página é sobre uma votação para criar um site dentro da rede do `StackOverFlow` somente sobre `programação IA` e está próximo de conseguir todos os votos e seguidores para continuar com o projeto.Isto não só irá te beneficiar mas também outros usuários que tem dúvidas semelhantes a sua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, caso você possua uma tabela referente aos dados das pessoas você pode tentar utilizar uma [árvore de decisão](http://aimotion.blogspot.com.br/2009/04/artigo-introducao-arvores-de-decisao.html), é uma técnica que você utiliza a tabela como base para formar uma árvore (esta será responsável pela inteligência do algoritmo). Há também os [sistemas baseados em regras](ftp://ftp.dca.fee.unicamp.br/pub/docs/vonzuben/ea072_2s11/topico6_EA072_2s11.pdf), que é, a grosso modo, uma cadeia inteligente de IFs e ELSES.

Infelizmente não tenho um conhecimento muito a fundo nessas áreas. Mas talvez esses dois assuntos possam servir como base para suas pesquisas.